# I have lists that contain a None value. I want to replace a none with some values as I describe using python

Tags: python, list

Here are some list that contain None value.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7, None, None, 3, None, None, None, 4, 5]
arr3= [None, 2, 3, 4, None, None, 3,4,5,1,2,None,None]
arr4 = [None, None, None, None, None, None,2,3,4,5]
arr5 = [1, None, None, 4, 5] 
arr6 =[None, 2, None, 1, None, None, None, None, None, 3, None]
arr7 =[None, None, None]
arr8 = [1,2,13,None,2,3]
```

I want output like

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7, 1, 2, 3,1,2,3,4,5]
arr3= [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3,4,5,1,2,3,4]
arr4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 1,2,3,4,5]
arr5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
arr6 =[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
arr7 =[1, 2, 3]
arr8 = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

I want a list that have a continue values like this .

for archive that I have tried this code . but it is not working good with some list. So, I Get output like this using python ?

I have tried this code.

```
prev_value = None
temp = None

for i in range(len(arr1)):
    if arr1[i] is not None:
        if temp is not None and temp > arr1[i]:
            diff = temp - arr1[i]
            for k in range(i - diff, i):
                arr1[k] = temp
                temp += 1
        else:
            prev_value = arr1[i]
            temp = None
    else:
        j = i
        while j < len(arr1) and arr1[j] is None:
            j += 1
        if j == len(arr1):
            break
        next_value = arr1[j]
        if prev_value is None:
            prev_value = next_value - (j - i)
        else:
            prev_value = max(prev_value, next_value - (j - i))
        for k in range(i, j):
            if prev_value < next_value:
                arr1[k] = prev_value
                prev_value += 1
                temp = prev_value - 1
            else:
                arr1[k] = next_value - 1
                temp = next_value - 1

print(arr1)
```

Comment: When the input is `arr6 =[None, 2, None, 1, None, None, None, None, None, 3, None]` and the correct result is `arr6 =[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, **how do you know this**? What logic should be used, to make it "wrap around" at 4? Why 4?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My guess: The partial sequences in the lists always start with 1 and increment by 1. If a `3` is there, previous two items must be `1, 2`. So in a first step `arr6` becomes `[1, 2, None, 1, None, None, None, 1, 2, 3, None]`. Then, based on existing numbers replace remaining `None`s incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

My approach iterates thrice over the list:

1. Numbers out of place are replaced
2. It finds pattern of `None, >1` and replaces this `None` and previous ones up to the given number `> 1`.
3. It replaces remaining `None`s with previous value plus one.

```
def fill(arr):

    arr[0] = 1
    
    # Step 1: Clean bad numbers
    prev = arr[0]

    for i, v in enumerate(arr[1:], 1):
        if prev is None:
            prev = v
            continue

        if v not in [None, 1, prev + 1]:
            # v is neither None, start of a subsequence (1) nor continuation of a subsequence
            # Make it a continuation
            arr[i] = prev + 1

        prev = v


    # Step 2: Fill backward
    prev = arr[0]
    
    for i, v in enumerate(arr[1:], 1):
        if v is not None and v > 1 and prev is None:
            # rewrite something like None, None, 3 to 1, 2, 3
            arr[i - v + 1 : i] = range(1, v)
            
        prev = v

    # Step 3: Fill forward
    prev = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        if v is not None:
            prev = v
            continue
        prev += 1
        arr[i] = prev
        

arr6 =[None, 2, None, 1, None, None, None, None, None, 3, None]
fill(arr6)

print(arr6)

arr8 = [1,2,13,None,2,3]
fill(arr8)
print(arr8)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It is working for all the list. but for list arr8 I am getting output like [1, 2, 13, 1, 2, 3] this. Is it possible that it replace the value 13 with 3 as 13 is not continue value . so that i got a output like **arr8 = [1,2,3,1,2,3]** this

Answer (score -1):

```py
src = [1, 2, ...]
# Describes the end indexes of sequences
seq = []

resolve = True

# Generate the sequences' end indexes
for i, v in enumerate(src[1:], 1):
  if v is None:
    resolve = True
  elif resolve:
    seq.append(i - v + 1)
    resolve = False

seq.append(len(src))

dest = []

# Iterate over the sequences
for v in seq:
  # v - len(dest) is just the sequence length
  for j in range(v - len(dest)):
    dest.append(j + 1)
```

I believe something like this should do the trick. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: No, it is not working . for arr3 I am getting [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2] this output as per your code. but I want [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3,4,5,1,2,3,4]. the code will be like if the next value is smaller then previous one, then start with 1,2,3 and so on . I am facing the problem is If 2 None are continue and then the next value is smaller . I am not getting proper output .

Comment: It is not working for arr3. i am getting output like [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] this.

Comment: You must be using the wrong code the wrong output array or the wrong input. Make sure you print out the dest array and pass the data in the source array.